# Plural possessive of category?

Tags: nouns, possessives

Example Sentence: The children of the category.

What does category become in this format: The `categor(ies|ies'|y's)` children?

Answer (score 1):

**Category** remains singular and **children** remains plural. The correct phrase is:

> The category's children...

However, it seems to me to be poor style and should be:

> The children in this category...

**[EDIT: Because SF's comment indicates a meaning different from the one I assumed]** or

> The children of this category...  (if you're talking about subcategories and not youngsters)

Comment: Of course if you want to multiply the categories, meaning "children of children" then *categories'* is the right word. Still, stylistically, "of category", "of categories" sounds much better.

Comment: You and I understand the OP's question differently. I took "children" at face value: kids. You're talking about subcategories. Your point is well taken. The question wasn't clear enough, perhaps. And, yes, if the categories are multiplied, it should be **categories'**. Perhaps it would be better as "the children **of** these categories"?